# Считывание файла в char* СИ

Tags: c

Всем доброго времени подскажите, пожалуйста, каким образом реализовать считывание файла в char* в СИ.

Comment: узнать размер, malloc - выделить, fread - прочитать. Где у Вас не получается?

Answer (score 1):

Если ты в линухе сидишь, то можешь воспользоваться функцией `read()` из
`unistd.h`. В отличие от `fread()` из `stdio.h`, - с помощью `read()`
можно читать нули (`\0`) и, в принципе, любые эскейп-последовательности.

Вот небольшой примерчик из моего проекта:

```
struct map *
map_read_map(const char *mpath) {
    struct map *map = malloc(sizeof(struct map));
    int fd;
    char *format = NULL;
    ssize_t br;
    size_t br_total = 0;
    
    fd = open(mpath, O_RDONLY);
    if (fd == -1)
        return NULL;
        
    do {
        format = realloc(format, 4096 + br_total + 1);

        br = read(fd, format + br_total, 4096);
        if (be == -1) {
            close(fd);
            free(format);

            perror("Read error");

            return NULL;
        }

        br_total += br;
    }
    while (br);

    format[br_total] = 0;

    ...
}
```

*Помимо `read()` я, также, использую функции `open()` и `close()`:
`close()` объявлён в том же `unistd.h`, а `open()` - в `fcntl.h`.
Ты мог заметить, что я использую необычные типы: `size_t` и `ssize_t`
(они определены в `sys/types.h`). На самом деле - это лишь
переносимые аналоги `int`-у и `unsigned int`-y (их размер не зависит
от архитектуры).*

Есть файл карты (в игре), которая имеет определённый формат, скажем
`size_x\nsize_y\npixels\n` (так выглядит пример файла карты:
`100\n200\n\255\255\0\255\100\255\255\0<...>\n`, где каждый пиксель
представлен в виде набора четырёх чисел: RGBA (backslash-и перед каждым числом
используются сугубо в интересах удобства чтения формата)). После многоточия я
работаю с ним. Но, перед тем как мне начать это делать, я должен
прочитать его в свою ОЗУ. Для этого я открываю файл и создаю указатель на него -
файловый дескриптор (обычное целое число), который получаю вызвав `open()`
по пути файла. Поскольку файл я изменять не собираюсь, мне будет достаточно
открыть его только для чтения:

```
    fd = open(mpath, O_RDONLY);
                     ^
```

У меня есть файловый дескриптор. Теперь, чтобы начать читать файл из него,
я могу воспользоваться `read()`-ом.

Смотри, `read()` принимает три аргумента: файловый дескриптор, буфер для чтения
и количество БАЙТ, которые следует прочитать из файла.

```
        br = read(fd, format + br_total, 4096);
             ^
```

Очевидно, я буду читать формат из файлового дескриптора `fd`. Но, куда? В обычный
фиксированный массив он либо влезет, либо не влезет. Как узнать наверняка: сколько
байтов потребуется для хранения всего файла? Можно через `stat()`, а можно
через `malloc()` (как я и делаю в примере). Я читаю файл по кусочкам,
фиксированными блоками (по 4096 байт за один раз). Буфер для чтения, в данном
примере, - это указатель на `char *`, который я аллоцирую тут:

```
        format = realloc(format, 4096 + br_total + 1);
```

Почему `realloc()`? Ну, это уже тонкости реализации. Если ты всё ещё сидишь в
linux, открой `man realloc` или вбей эти слова в поисковик.

`br` - это возвращаемое значение `read()`-а. Суть в том (я подвожу к объяснению:
почему `format` складывается с `br_total`), что возвращает `read()`, в основном -
количество прочитанных байт из файла. Насколько я знаю, `read()` может прочитать
из файла меньше байт, чем ты ему сказал, если ты читаешь байты из сетевого
сокета. Потому, в этом примере можешь считать, что либо `read()` возвращает
размер файла (если он меньше 4096 байт), либо 4096. Что делать если файл
больше 4096 байт? Думаю, ответ получается слишком большим, поэтому скажу
коротко: ты читаешь в области `format` - записал 4096 в самое начало
`format`-а, выделил ещё 4096 байт под указатель, записал в следующую
4096-байтную область `format` данные, и так далее, пока файл не закончится.
Чтобы в строке формата не оказалось мусора (скажем, размер файла оказался
8180 байт) от `realloc()`-скового `malloc()`-а, можно поставить последний байт
`format`-а в 0 (или в `\0`):

```
    format[br_total] = 0;
                       ^
```

Если ты заметил, то да - именно поэтому я делаю `realloc()` `format`-а на
`4096 + br_total + 1` (чтобы не стереть последний прочитанный `\n`).

`br_total` - это просто тотальное количество байт, которое было прочитано за
весь цикл. Вообще, было бы красивее написать `br_total + 4096 + 1`...
Потому что `br_total` - это все байты, которые ты успел прочитать на момент
очередной итерации; 4096 - это сколько байт ты хочешь выделить дополнительно
под `format`; ну и 1 - это байт для нуля, который ставится в конец `format`-a
двумя строчками выше от многоточия.

Как правильно открывать файлы в винде - для меня загадка. Но, если тебе не
нужно читать из файла нули, можешь воспользоваться функцией `fread()` (вообще,
`fread()`-ом и нули читать можно, но для этого придётся писать свой парсер...).

Comment: [fstat()](https://linux.die.net/man/2/fstat) читает в т.ч. и размер файла. Соответственно, все припрыгивания с `realloc` не нужны